# Syntax error on create query.Please guide

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE Report AS 
 (SELECT b.Id, 
  (CASE WHEN b.Svc_Id = 3 THEN 'NET MARKET'
        WHEN b.Svc_Id = 8 THEN 'NET SAL'
        WHEN b.Svc_Id = 7 THEN 'NET RESAT'
        WHEN b.Svc_Id = 20 THEN 'NET TAX'
  END) as CurrSvcId,
  b.Classification,
  (CASE WHEN a.NewSvcId = 6 THEN 'Priority Low'
        WHEN a.NewSvcId = 9 THEN 'Priority Medium'
        WHEN a.NewSvcId = 21 THEN 'Priority High'
  END) as SINewSvcCd,
  b.Login_Name
  FROM Market_Data b, Report a
  WHERE ((b.Svc_Id = 3 and a.NewSvcId = 0) OR (b.Svc_Id = 3 AND a.NewSvcId > 0 ))
    AND a.Flag = 0 AND b.User_Id = a.User_Id
    AND a.Status = 'ACTIVE'
    AND a.RetCode = 0 order by b.SvcId
 )
```

I get a error stating missing right paranthesis. Please help me on this

Comment: Did you even look at your question? It's unreadable and without the exact error message hard to answer.

Comment: @peter I am not able to edit this with spaces

Comment: Your part of statement `((b.Svc_Id = 3 and a.NewSvcId = 0) OR (b.Svc_Id = 3 AND a.NewSvcId > 0 ))` is equivalent to `b.Svc_Id = 3 AND a.NewSvcId >= 0`.

Comment: @user472625 - the question editor has a formatting toolbar.  Highhlight your code snippet and click the `{}` button to format it properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE Report AS 
   SELECT b.Id, 
        ( CASE b.Svc_Id
             WHEN 3 
             THEN 'NET MARKET' 
             WHEN 8 
             THEN 'NET SAL' 
             WHEN 7 
             THEN 'NET RESAT' 
             WHEN 20 
             THEN 'NET TAX' 
           END ) as CurrSvcId, 
        b.Classification, 
        ( CASE a.NewSvcId
             WHEN 6 
             THEN 'Priority Low' 
             WHEN 9 
             THEN 'Priority Medium' 
             WHEN 21 
             THEN 'Priority High' 
           END ) as SINewSvcCd, 
        b.Login_Name 
   FROM Market_Data b, 
        Report a 
  WHERE (b.Svc_Id = 3 AND a.NewSvcId >= 0 )
    AND a.Flag = 0 
    AND b.User_Id = a.User_Id 
    AND a.Status = 'ACTIVE' 
    AND a.RetCode = 0 
  order by b.SvcId;
```

You should add an "ELSE" section to both of your "CASE" statements to trap any other values that might occur (however unlikely).

The "ORDER BY" clause might be spurious, do you really need the rows entered into a RDBMS table in a specific order? You might but generally you won't, consider whether you need it or not.

You might also want to consider a storage clause etc. if you are unsure, speak to your DBA about it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Then don't add the ORDER BY clause, as I stated in my answer, you don't need it. When you query a database table, if you need the results in a specific order you should use the ORDER BY clause then. Never RELY on the order that records are inserted into a table as the order they will be returned in a select query.